# Classification PDE, 2 order

Tags: partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, partial-derivative

Classificate the following Partial differential equations of order 2:
$$a)\sum_{i=1}^n(-1)^{i(i+1)}\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_i^2}=0$$$$b) \sum_{i,j=1}^n (-1)^{i+j} \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}=0$$

For the classification i look at the eigenvalues of the coefficient-matrix A with $A_{ij}=a_{ij}$ of $\sum_{i,j=1}^n a_{ij} \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_i^2}$.

In a) i become $A=E_n$, so $(\lambda_1,..,\lambda_n)=(1,..,1) \rightarrow $elliptic

In b) i have $A= \begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 &1 &\dots \\
-1 & 1 & -1 & \dots \\
1 & -1 & 1 & \dots\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \ddots
\end{pmatrix}$

I try to calculate the determinant and think $det(A)=0$, so it exists a eigenvalue $0$ and the equation isn´t elliptic. The Hurwitz criterium doesn´t help me to decide if the equation is hyperbolic or parabolic and i don´t know how i can calculate the eigenvalues of A.

For n=1 the equation is elliptic.

Comment: Add row $k+1$ to row $k$ for all $k=1,2,3,4,\ldots,n-1$ to the matrix $A-\lambda I$ and then manipulate the last row to $\{0,0,,\ldots,n-\lambda\}$ using the other row to find that the eigenvalues of $A$ are $\lambda = 0$ (with multiplicity $n-1$) and $\lambda = n$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don´t understand how you manipulate the matrix to reach $\{0,0,..0,n-\lambda\}$ in the last row. Can you explain that?

Comment: Multiply row $1$ by $\pm 1/\lambda$ (assume $\lambda \not =0$) and add to the last row. Do a similar thing for row $2,3\ldots$. Before doing it in general you might want to do this for $n=2,3,4$ first.

Comment: Thanks, this is now clear for me. I have one question left: Why you can assume that $\lambda \not=0 $ and then conclude that $\lambda=0$?

Comment: You already know that $\lambda = 0$ is an eigenvalue since $\det A = 0$. This shows that $\lambda = n \not= 0$ is also an eigenvalue.

Comment: Or without calculating the determinante: I know from your calculation that $\lambda=n$ is a eigenvalue with multiplicity $1$ and the other eigenvalues (if their exists) must be 0 because i exlude this case in the calculation. Because a symmetric matrix can be diagonalised i infer that the other $n-1$ eigenvalues must be 0. Is this okay?

Comment: That sounds good. Or using that a $n\times n$ matrix always have $n$ eigenvalues (in $\mathbb{C}$) when counted with multiplicity.

Comment: @Winther: that should be an answer (or maybe Lauren Veganer can write up a version and accept it? Self answers are allowed on this site.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To classify the PDE $\sum a_{ij} \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x_i \partial x_j} + \sum b_i \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i} = f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ we need to find the eigenvalues of the matrix $A$ with coefficients $a_{ij}$. If $A$ has $0$ as en eigenvalue then the PDE is parabolic (caveat; some books require all non-zero eigenvalues to have the same sign for it to be parabolic). If none of the eigenvalues are zero and all or none are positive then the PDE is elliptic. Otherwise it's hyperbolic or ultrahyperbolic. See e.g. [Wiki::PDE Classifications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_differential_equation#Classification) (and [these notes](http://how.gi.alaska.edu/ao/sim/chapters/chap3.pdf) for a slightly different definition than on Wikipedia).

Let's apply this to your problem (b) where $a_{ij} = (-1)^{ij}$ so

$$A = \pmatrix{1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & \cdots \\ -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & \cdots \\ 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & \cdots \\ \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots}$$

If $n > 2$ then (atleast) two of the rows in $A$ are seen to be equal which implies $\det A = 0$ and $0$ is an eigenvalue making the PDE parabolic. The same applies for $n=2$ as a direct computation shows. When $n=1$ then the PDE ($u_{xx} = 0$) is elliptic.

Depending on the classification definition you use you might not need to explicitly compute all the eigenvalues of $A$ to solve the problem at hand: either it's parabolic of it does not fall within the classification. For completeness I'll add some notes on how one might proceed to compute all the eigenvalues of $A$ as it's a nice little problem.

---

Consider the matrix $A - \lambda I$. Start by adding row $k+1$ to row $k$ for $k=1,2,\ldots,n-1$ to arrive at the matrix

$$\pmatrix{-\lambda & -\lambda & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\ 0 &-\lambda & -\lambda & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & -\lambda & -\lambda & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots &\cdots & \cdots\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & -\lambda & -\lambda\\(-1)^{n+1} & (-1)^{n} & (-1)^{n+1} & (-1)^{n} & (-1)^{n+1} & \cdots & -1 & 1-\lambda}$$

Now assume $\lambda \not= 0$ and add $\pm \frac{1}{\lambda}$ of row 1 to the last row (sign depending on the parity of $n$), then $\pm\frac{2}{\lambda}$ of row 2 to the last row, then $\pm\frac{3}{\lambda}$ or row $3$ and so on until we have transformed it to the form

$$\pmatrix{-\lambda & -\lambda & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\ 0 &-\lambda & -\lambda & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & -\lambda & -\lambda & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots &\cdots & \cdots\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & -\lambda & -\lambda\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & n-\lambda}$$

for which we can read off that the characteristic equation $0 = \det(A-\lambda I)$  is proportional to $\lambda^{n-1}(\lambda -n)$ so $\lambda = n$ is the only possible non-zero eigenvalue. The eigenvalue $0$ must therefore have multiplicity $n-1$.